# How to get table header onClick to row cell in html table?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a table with checkboxes, I want to get table header of a specific row cell on click to checkboxes in table row cells. It will only return the header where the clicked cell is. I am trying to do something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5dgmxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr >
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col" *ngFor="let columnNames of tableHeaderNames">{{columnNames}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let role of roles; let i = index">
        <td >{{role}}</td>
        <td ><input (click)="select($event)" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td ><input (click)="select($event)" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td ><input (click)="select($event)" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td ><input (click)="select($event)" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td ><input (click)="select($event)" type="checkbox"></td>
        
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  public tableHeaderNames = [
    "Header1",
    "Header2",
    "Header3",
    "Header4",
    "Header5"
  ];
  public roles = [
    "Role1",
    "Role2",
    "Role3",
    "Role4",
    "Role5",
    "Role6",
    "Role7"
  ];

  select(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already hardcoding in the `td` elements you could just pass a value into the click function, like:

```
<td ><input (click)="select($event, 0)" type="checkbox"></td>
<td ><input (click)="select($event, 1)" type="checkbox"></td>
<td ><input (click)="select($event, 2)" type="checkbox"></td>
```

Then the `select` function gets the index as the second value and looks up the corresponding `tableHeaderNames` value, like:

```
select(e, index) {
    console.log(this.tableHeaderNames[index])
}
```

---

Additionally, a better way to do this without hardcoding is to generate the `td` elements dynamically per the number of header elements there are. You can then pass in the header name directly into the `select` function, like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let role of roles">
  <td>{{ role }}</td>
  <td *ngFor="let roleColumn of tableHeaderNames; let i = index">
    <input (click)="select($event, roleColumn)" type="checkbox">
  </td>
</tr>
```

I can dynamically pass through the `roleColumn` value which will contain the header name.